# How to make a sprite more opaque in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, transparency

I am making a 2D game in Unity 3D. I have a few sprites, but they are so transparent that I can barely see them when the game is running. How can I make them more opaque?

Comment: Can you provide any screenshot? Are your sprites transparent in Photoshop also? Need more info to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The textures used for the sprites could be semi-transparent, the [SpriteRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) component color alpha value could be set somewhere between transparent and opaque, or the [Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) could have semi-transparent aspects.  Try checking all 3 of these possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that it's easier to do it with GIMP. I open the file representing the spite with GIMP. I select the parts of the sprite from witch I want to remove the transparency using the fuzzy selector (Tools->Selection->Fuzzy), I click on each of them with the right mouse button and choose Level->Tranparency-> Remove alpha channel.

That's pretty much it.